# jQuery & Javascript - Loop Slowly Through an Object's Properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, timing

Let's say I have this code:

```
var a = ["a", "b", "c"];
a.forEach(function(entry) {
    setTimeout(function() { 
        console.log(entry); 
    }, 1000);
});
```

This waits 1 second and then logs `a`, `b`, and `c` all at once. I want to wait 1 second, log `a`, wait another second, log `b`, wait a third second, log `c`.

How do I execute a for loop so that each loop takes a second, and the following loops don't start until that second is up?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `setInterval()` and `clearInterval()` to accomplish you task.

Try,

```
 var xCnt = 0;
 var a = ["a", "b", "c"];

 var xInterval = setInterval(function () {
     console.log(a[xCnt]);
     xCnt += 1;
     if (xCnt == a.length) {
         clearInterval(xInterval);
     }
 }, 1000);
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/P2QGN/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var i = -1;
var int = setInterval(loop, 1000);

function loop(){
  if( i >=0 && i < a.length){
    console.log(a[i]);
    i++;
  }
  else{ clearInterval(int);}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try multiplying the setTimeout by the index argument in forEach, like this:

```
var a = ["a", "b", "c"];
a.forEach(function(entry, index) {
    setTimeout(function() { 
        console.log(entry); 
    }, 1000 * (index + 1));
});
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/tjnicolaides/A8rvX/